# Sqlite database onUpgrade() does not get called

Tags: java, android, sqlite, upgrade

I am working on an android application where i used existing sqlite database in the asset folder. So i actually copy the database from that folder. User can also save their own data(mark any content as favorite).

I uploaded a version in the market. Now i want to add some new data in the database and uploaded a new version. If user update the app from the market i want to keep the user data(from previous version) and add the new data as well. I have done some google and found that on upgrade method should do the trick. But I am changing the DATABASE_VERSION from code but the on upgrade method does not get call. I am wondering i have missed something. Here is my code:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/riskycoder.login/databases/";
public static String DB_NAME = "datenbank_EN.sqlite";
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private final Context myContext;
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;





public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (dbExist) {
    } else {
        this.getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            this.close();
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }

}

private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
    }
    if (checkDB != null)
        checkDB.close();
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

    //myDataBase.setVersion(DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    Log.d("Test", "Database version: " +myDataBase.getVersion());
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.d("Test", "in onUpgrade. Old is: " + oldVersion + " New is: " + newVersion);


}
```

}

Comment: *I am changing the DATABASE_VERSION from code..*, what exactly does this means? I see you call the super constructor of the `SQLiteOpenHelper` with a constant field `DATABASE_VERSION`(which obviously can't be changed), so how exactly do you change the database version?

Comment: In new version of the application i have changed the DATABASE_VERSION to 2. So while installing the new version the onUpgrade method should be called. Or i am missing something?

Comment: First, the code you posted showa DATABASE_VERSION is 1, so onUpgrade wouldn't be called.  Second, even if it was 2, your onUpgrade has no code to do anythign to update the database.  It doesn't happen automagically, you have to do it.

Comment: I'm facing same problem did  you able to solve this.

Comment: can someone please help me i am also facing difficulty to upgrade the database of assets folder

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`onUpgrade()` is only called if a change in the database version number is detected. Increment the database version as follows:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
```

Comment: Won't do him much good as all onUpgrade does is spit out a log message (at least with the posted code)

Comment: The OP asked "why doesn't the `onUpgrade` method get called." Of course it will only spit out a log message as he has not yet implemented `onUpgrade`.

Comment: @AlexLockwood-> I have changed the DATABASE_VERSION to 2 as you said but nothing shown in the logcat output. I have created the database by sqlite browser. Should i do any versioning while creating the database?

Comment: `onUpgrade` is called ONLY WHEN your app detects a change in the `DATABASE_VERSION` number. Thus, simply incrementing the version number will cause `onUpgrade` to be called once and it will not be called again until the version number is changed again (i.e. by incrementing the number to 3).

Comment: when getReadableDatabase() or getWritableDatabase is called onUpgrde method get called

Comment: @AlexLockwood i changed database version and tried but onUpgrade() is not called. My question link is:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20192642/android-onupgrade-not-calling-at-database-upgrade. Please visit and suggest me.

Answer (score 6):

Change your onUpgrade to the following

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            if(newVersion > oldVersion){                    
                    myContext.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME);
            }
        }
```

And also change your createDataBase() like below,

```
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

            if(dbExist){
                // By calling this method here onUpgrade will be called on a
                // writable database, but only if the version number has been increased

                this.getWritableDatabase();
            }

            dbExist = checkDataBase();

            if(!dbExist){

                //By calling this method an empty database will be created into the                     default system path
                   //of the application so we will be able to overwrite that database with our database.
                this.getReadableDatabase();

                try {

                    copyDataBase();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    throw new Error("Error copying database");

                }
            }

        }
```

At the end increase your database version and run it again. `onUpgrade` doesn't get called till you call `getReadableDatabase()` or similar functions.

Hope this helps

Comment: i have followed your answer but still my onUpgrade method is not being called can u pls help me

Answer (score 2):

Try this (increase the DATABASE_VERSION) & the onUpdate() will be called:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
```

Comment: @Barak-> I have placed log.d statement in onUpgrade() to test. But i dont see anything in the logcat output. That means the onUpgrade does not get called. In openDataBase() method i have put a log.d statement. I can see the database version is always 1 even if i change the DATABASE_VERSION to 2.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you did change the DATABASE_VERSION, you still have to put code in the onUpgrade to make it happen.  It's not magical, you have to tell it what to do.

In your case you need to:

1)  copy the old database (give it a new name) 
2)  copy in your new database 
3)  read the data from the old database
4)  copy any differences into the new database
5)  delete the old database

**EDIT**

Assuming you ship the DB in the assets folder you would copy it for use like so:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // First copy old db
    InputStream bakInput = getActivity().getAssets().open(dbname);
    String bakFileName = getActivity().getAssets() + "YourDB.old";
    OutputStream bakOutput = new FileOutputStream(bakFileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = bakInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        bakOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

    // delete the old db
    File delDB = new File(getActivity().getAssets() + "YourDB"); 
    boolean deleted = file.delete(); 

    // Copy in the new db
    InputStream myInput = getActivity().getAssets().open("YourDB");
    String outFileName = MAIN_DB_PATH + dbname;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

    // add code here to get changes user has made to db and move them to updated db

    // delete the old db copy
    File delDB = new File(getActivity().getAssets() + "YourDB.old"); 
    boolean deleted = file.delete(); 
}
```

Comment: Sorry i dont get you. In my case how do i copy new database. can you please post some code how do i do that.......sorry for my silly question...

Comment: @Barak can u help me my onUpgrade method is not being called